# How to run nginx docker underlying docker-entrypoint.sh

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm using this in my Dockerfile, without CMD or ENTRYPOINT. I'm relying on the underlying nginx official image's docker-entrypoint.sh

```
FROM nginx:1.18
```

I've tried in my docker-compose to add the following command but it just keeps restarting and no error msg.

```
command: >
    sh -c 'echo "My Own Command" && /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"'
```

It will work fine if I remove the command from my docker-compose.yml.

**My final objective** is to add some scripts so I can export secrets to my environment variable but I couldn't get the underlying docker-entrypoint.sh or nginx-g "daemon off;" command running and keeping the container going.

Comment: Your command works with `nginx:latest` but not with `nginx:1.18`. There are some differences in how the images are built (1.18 doesn't have a docker-entrypoint.sh script for instance). Can you use the latest version or does it have to be 1.18?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 18.04 and it comes with 1.18 nginx and we didn’t upgrade because we don’t want to break things. i will give the latest a go and see if it works! thank you very much!